# respone.Write(string) - also copies the wesite after th string

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

xml is a string

```
Response.Write(xml);
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=databaseXml.xml");
```

problem:
After writing the content of the xml string, it  writes the webpage too.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a Response.End at the end?

Answer (score 0):

For scenarios like this, usually I make an **empty page** (*like export.aspx without any HTML, only code behind*)  and do the job at that page, not same page as what ever I do.

But **this is my opinion**, *happy to hear other solutions*.